# In R, is there a more memory-efficient alternative to using 'group_by' followed by 'mutate'

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using a large dataset and trying to get some summary statistics. In particular, I want to find a mean/ SD for the number of unique drugs that a group of patients were prescribed (i.e. I already have the mean/SD for the total count of drugs, but I want to also reflect the number of *different* drugs a patient was on, on average).

The following piece of code has worked for previous (smaller) groups but lines 2 to 4 in particular seem to be slowing things down.

```
DF %>% 
group_by(patientID) %>%
mutate(total_unique_med = n_distinct(drug_name) %>%
ungroup() %>%
summarise(   
mean = mean(total_unique_med),
sd = sd(total_unique_med) )
```

Is there a more approprate/ memory-efficient alternative to group_by/ mutate to use when working with large datasets?

Comment: This should already be fairly fast, you could try using data.table which could be faster. Are we talking about 1 million, 10 million, 100 million patients?

Comment: Maybe `data.table` can be faster for you. Try doing `setDT(DF)[, total_unique_med := uniqueN(drug_name), by = patientID][, .(mean = mean(total_unique_med), sd = sd(total_unique_med))]`